# AWS Admin has no EC2 Describe operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have an IAM role with `AdministratorAccess`, but when I upload a custom template to [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/), I get the following error:

> Operation failed, ComputeEnvironment went INVALID with error:
> CLIENT_ERROR - You are not authorized to call EC2 Describe operations.
> It is required to perform CreateLaunchConfiguration operation.

All the other resources seem to complete successfully, so I'm not sure if there is some sort of role delegation taking place?

Comment: can you run it directly (not through cloudformation)?

Comment: Yea, running `aws ec2 describe-instances` from my CLI configured user works fine.

I wonder if some permissions aren't propagated to cloud formation even though the role has admin access.

Comment: or maybe the command isn't running under the role. hate to say - but requires a lot of troubleshooting. You say *role* - the role is assigned to a server instance. When you run CF templates, usually it is running under user and permissions assigned to the *user*.  Are you sure you mean role?

Comment: I created a new user belonging to the `AdministratorAccess` group and configured my ~/.aws/credentials with the new keys.

After trying both `aws --debug cloudformation create-stack --template-url <url> --stack-name my_stack --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM` and replacing the capabilities with `CAPABILITY_IAM`, I keep seeing the same thing.

Will keep trying to look for some helpful debug logs...

Comment: In [AWS CloudFormation service role - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html), it mentions that CloudFormation can use a _Service Role_ attached to a stack. When you launch this template, is it specifying an IAM Role (console step #3)? In fact, have you tried launching it via the console?

Comment: John, this indeed seems to have been the issue.

On the 2nd step of creating a stack, I had to set `CustomRole` to `true` AND specify the IAM role on 3rd step (admin in my case). Any other permutation (true + no role, false + role, false + no role) did not work. I'm going to investigate further and fully understand why this is the case and then answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are affected by [Service Control Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html#scp-effects-on-permissions) (SCPs) or by [Permission Boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html) or even other [policy types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#access_policy-types).

- [Identity-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_id-based)
- [Resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_resource-based)
- [Permissions boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_bound)
- [Organization SCPs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_scp)
- [Access control lists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_acl)
- [Session policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_session)

Regarding SCPs:

> An SCP restricts permissions for IAM users and roles in member
> accounts, including the member account's root user. Any account has
> only those permissions permitted by every parent above it. If a
> permission is blocked at any level above the account, either
> implicitly (by not being included in an Allow policy statement) or
> explicitly (by being included in a Deny policy statement), a user or
> role in the affected account can't use that permission, even if the
> account administrator attaches the AdministratorAccess IAM policy with
> */* permissions to the user.

Also see [How to use service control policies to set permission guardrails across accounts in your AWS Organization](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-service-control-policies-to-set-permission-guardrails-across-accounts-in-your-aws-organization/)

As [this article](https://summitroute.com/blog/2020/03/25/aws_scp_best_practices/) states,

> The member accounts of an AWS Organization are unable to see the SCPs
> that have been applied to them. Further, when actions are denied,
> there is no way to know whether that is due to an IAM policy, an SCP,
> or something else (ex. session policy, IAM boundary, resource policy).
> This means there will be no indication in the error message from an
> API call or in the CloudTrail log to show what denied the call. This
> can make debugging issues difficult.

[This article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html) has some useful diagrams that show the different things that could be affecting/limiting the access.

Comment: Possible, but highly unlikely. OP doesn't say anything about AWS Organizations, and if everything else works - it's probably a single organization setup

Comment: That is correct. There are no SCPs because it is a personal account and there aren't any permission boundaries either.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this problem for four days and finally came up with a solution that I think resolves it.

There are two kinds of CDK bootstrap: legacy and modern. Legacy is the default.

There appears to be a bug in the legacy bootstrap that affects some accounts and not others. I was able to verify that the same code worked for me on one account but produced the exact symptoms of this problem on a newly created account.

If you are not stuck with legacy bootstrap for some reason, just convert over to modern bootstrap. That should make the error (and the reason for the error) go away.

The instructions are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html

Basically, you have to set an environment variable before you call `cdk bootstrap`, and then you have to change either some code or some configuration in your project.

It is not intuitive that this feature exists in the CDK at all, nor that it would be the fix for this particular problem. However, it cleared it up for me. Maybe it will do the same for others.